# October CMS' Magic Forms plug-in how to catch multi select values?

Tags: octobercms

I have a multi select field in a complex form. It's works on the Magic Forms. But Magic Forms only handle multi select's values last one.

#### An example

```html
                  <select required multiple id="..." name="...">
                    <option value="HTML">
                      HTML
                    </option>
                    <option value="CSS">
                      CSS
                    </option>
                    <option value="JavaScript">
                      JavaScript
                    </option>
                    <option value="Node.js">
                      Node.js
                    </option>
                  </select>
```

If I select HTML & CSS options, Magic Forms handle and record only the CSS option. I searched little bit, but I can't it. Is there a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you just need to make minor adjustments with the `select name`.

[Ref](https://coderecharge.com/october-cms/magic-form/october-cms-magic-forms-how-catch-multi-select-values) : [Multiselect in OctoberCMS Magic Form](https://plus.google.com/url?q=https://coderecharge.com/october-cms/magic-form/october-cms-magic-forms-how-catch-multi-select-values)

As when you select multiple items it becomes `an array`. to represent the array on the HTML side you need to add `[]` square braces to the name.

> Suppose your current select name is `tech` So your select name becomes `tech[]` as now we are representing multiple values so it becomes `an array`.

```html
<select required multiple id="tech" name="tech[]">
<!--                     USE name like THIS ^ -->
  <option value="HTML">
    HTML
  </option>
  <option value="CSS">
    CSS
  </option>
  <option value="JavaScript">
    JavaScript
  </option>
  <option value="Node.js">
    Node.js
  </option>
</select>
```

> It will work and in backend records, it will show something like this :

[image: magic-form-backend-record-list]

If any doubt please comment.